# C++ function overloading with "constant"

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have been coding graph algorithms and I came up with this problem. In c++11
I tried to create a structure like below,

```
struct edges{
  int u , v , w ;
  edges(){}
  edges( int _u , int _v , int _w ) {
    u = _u , v = _v , w = _w ;
  }
  bool operator < ( edges & r ) {
    return w < r.w ;
  }
};
```

So, I wrote this code, **it compiles successfully**.
But when I call **std::sort()** function like below,

```
sort( arr , arr + M ) ; // here arr is an array of edges with M elements
```

Then I get compilation error which points to **stl_algo.h** line number **2242**. I am adding the portion of code from stl_algo.h,

```
/// This is a helper function...
  template<typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _Tp>
    _RandomAccessIterator
    __unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator __first,
              _RandomAccessIterator __last, const _Tp& __pivot)
    {
      while (true)
    {
      while (*__first < __pivot)   // 2242 number line
        ++__first;
      --__last;
      while (__pivot < *__last)
        --__last;
      if (!(__first < __last))
        return __first;
      std::iter_swap(__first, __last);
      ++__first;
    }
    }
```

So then I find solution in the Internet and got one. I have to overload the operator with **const** keyword like below,

```
struct edges{
  int u , v , w ;
  edges(){}
  edges( int _u , int _v , int _w ) {
    u = _u , v = _v , w = _w ;
  }
  bool operator < ( const edges & r ) const {
    return w < r.w ;
  }
};
```

**My question is why I have overload the operator with 'const' keyword if I call std::sort() function ?**

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I couldn't find any such requirement in the standard though. The closest it comes is `It is assumed that comp will not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterator.` It looks to me like an implementation defect that `__pivot` is made `const`.

Comment: What compiler / OS? Also, what is `arr`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: compiler g++11 and OS is debian linux(ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator < is used to **compare** two objects, and the object that is passed by parameter will **not be altered**, so the parameter must be **const**.